# python regular expression involving backslash

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract all latex expressions from a file, i.e. strings between `$` and `$` which are not between `\$` and `\$`

Consider the followingg:

```
import re
with open("abstracts.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    l = f.read()

with open("latex.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for a in re.findall(r"[^\\]\$.*?[^\\]\$",l,re.S):  
        f.write(a+"\n")
```

This works as I need, but it includes the dollar signs. However when I change (*) to

```
    for a in re.findall(r"[^\\]\$(.*?)[^\\]\$",l,re.S):  #(*)
```

it doesn't do what I want. For example the string `$\overline{\tilde \ch_0}$` gets transformed to `\overline{\tilde \ch_0`.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the "which are not between \$ and \$" part mean? I don't see it being addressed anywhere in your code.

Comment: As a side note, use [raw string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=literal#string-literals) for regexes to avoid escaping confusion. E.g. in `\$`, the backslash is unescaped on Python level.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I've taken the liberty of doing that in OP's code, to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is matching the character immediately before the dollar sign.  I would recommend using negative lookbehind instead:

```
for a in re.findall(r"(?<!\\)\$(.*?)(?<!\\)\$",l,re.S):
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the negative lookbehind technique., which indeed seems natural here.